# Using polar co-ordinates to find the fixed point of the dynamical system $x^\prime = x-y-x^{3}$ and $y^\prime = x+y-y^{3}$.

Tags: polar-coordinates, chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Using polar co-ordinates to solve the dynamical system:
$$x^\prime = x-y-x^{3}$$

$$y^\prime = x+y-y^{3}$$
I would say that I mostly understand this question and need to manipulate the equations using the following known conversions:
$x = r$cos$(\theta)$, $y=r$sin$(\theta)$, $x^{2} + y^{2} = r^{2}$ and $rr^\prime = xx^\prime + yy^\prime $ and $\theta' = \dfrac{x y' - y x'}{r^2}$

I have made a a start with the following attempt but have become stuck at this stage:
\begin{align}
rr^\prime &= xx^\prime + yy^\prime 
\\
&=x(x-y-x^{3}) + y(x+y-y^{3})
\\
&=x^{2} -xy - x^{4} + yx + y^{2} - y^{4}
\\
&=(x^{2} + y^{2}) - (x^{4} + y^{4})
\\
&=(r^{2}) - (x^{4} + y^{4})
\end{align}
It is at this point that I am stuck as I struggle to see how I can simplify the last line further in terms of r, even though I am fairly certain this is the course of action I need to take. Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the first two relations you mentioned: $ x = r \cos\theta $ and
$ y = r \sin\theta $. The term $ x^4 + y^4 $ then becomes
$ r^4( \cos^4\theta + \sin^4\theta ) $, and you end up with
$ r' = r - r^3 (\cos^4\theta + \sin^4\theta) $. You can then do a similar development for $\theta' = \frac{xy' - yx'}{r^2} $ to obtain a system in the form
\begin{align}
  r' &= f(r, \theta)\\
  \theta' &= g(r, \theta)
\end{align}

Comment: Okay great, this was my answer for r^\prime also but I assumed it would be a simpler function without the theta terms as it has been in previous examples of this type of question that I've seen. I have carried out the substitutions to obtain $ \theta' = 1 + r^2 (\cos^3\theta\sin\theta + \sin^3\theta\cos\theta) $. Is this correct? And how would I then proceed to find the fixed point of the system? Thanks

Comment: It's almost right, there should be a minus sign in front of the term $ \sin^3 \theta \cos \theta $, which allows you to simplify further using identities for $\sin 2\theta$ and $ \cos 2\theta$: $ \theta' = 1 + \frac{r^2}{4} \sin 4\theta $. To find fixed points, look for solutions of the system $$ \left\{ \begin{array}  ff(r,\theta) &= 0\\ g(r,\theta) &= 0 \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Great thanks for spotting this minor sign error. So we have $\theta' = 1+\dfrac{r^2}{4}sin4\theta$ 

$ r' = r - r^3 (\cos^4\theta + \sin^4\theta) $ and I understand that making them both equal to zero is what gets our equillibrium/fixed point but I'm still unclear on how this helps finding the solution. Could you perhaps talk me through this?

Comment: Further to this, the question specifically ask to show that the system has a fixed point at a distance smaller than 2 from the origin. I understand that this would mean the fixed point has $r<2$ correct? And I suppose that finding the fixed point would be sufficient to show this condition exists?

Comment: Indeed. However this diverges from the initial question, so I would suggest posting a new one if there is something else that you don't understand/need help with.

Comment: Great, I have just posted a new question with regards to this. Would be much appreciated if you had any contribution with regards to this.